# Node.js: fs.readdir does not return a file written by fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous

## My app

A simple Node.js http server which creates files in a given directory by calling `POST /deploy`. After the file is written, I want to list all the files in that directory using `console.log`.

For creating files (`POST /deploy`), I call:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', callback(null, {'newFile': filename}));
```

The callback writes the HTTP response and lists the files using:

```
fs.readdir(some_directory, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
        // Do something with the file
    }
}
```

## My problem

**The new file is not listed in the callback.** Only after I call deploy again, the previous file is listed. For example, if I create files `a` and `b` using `/deploy` consecutively, `a` is listed only when `b` is created and `b` is not listed until I make another call.

I assume the file is not closed when the callback is called, so that only later calls to `fs.readdir` see the file, after it has been closed.

**How can I call the callback function only after the file is properly closed and can be listed using `fs.readdir`?**

## What have I tried

- Reading the [`fs.close()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) manual. It works, but requires an `fd`, not a filename, so I have to open the files just for closing it, which seems cumbersome:

  fs.open(filename, 'w', function(error, fd) {
      fs.write(fd, content, function(err, written, buffer) {
          fs.close(fd, callback(null, {'newFile': filename}));
      });
  });
- Searching for similar problems in SO

Comment: The callback looks suspicious. it seems you already call the callback on `fs.writefile` instead letting the function call you back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', callback(null, {'newFile': filename}));
```

In the code above you run the callback immediately, without waiting for the operation to finish. It would work only if your call to `callback(null, {'newFile': filename})` actually returned a function to call as a callback, which I doubt it does.

This may help:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', () => callback(null, {'newFile': filename}));
```

because here the `callback()` will be called after the write operation finishes. But this is still not enough because you need to handle errors:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle possible errors
  } else {
    callback(null, {'newFile': filename});
  }
});
```

e.g. if your `callback` can take error as the first argument you could do:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
  } else {
    callback(null, {'newFile': filename});
  }
});
```

or returning early you can avoid `else`:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, content, 'utf8', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  callback(null, {'newFile': filename});
});
```

Comment: Ba-Bam! Nailed it like a Ninja. Thanks. Regarding the errors - I'm teaching my self some Node.js basics following a tutorial, so I can disregard them for now - they're just not the focus of what I'm trying to achieve.